# How to persist batch ID when working with opaque state in Trident?

Tags: apache-storm, trident

I'm getting this error when re-running Trident topology using local cluster:

```
Current batch (1) is behind state's batch
```

Previous transaction ID is stored in Cassandra along with a counter value, but it seems like transaction ID is always set to 1 at the beginning, thus simple validation step (current transaction ID is greater than previous transaction ID) always fails.

How to make Trident persist the current batch ID?

Thanks!